# In Spring Security, access is not applied properly on intercept url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I wrote following code in my project-security.xml file.

```
<security:http name="dbservice" pattern="/pages" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="WMSecAuthEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Test" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_admin')"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http name="common" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="WMSecAuthEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app.variables.json" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/topnav/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/rightnav/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/leftnav/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/header/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/footer/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Main/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:request-cache ref="nullRequestCache"/>
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="WMSecAuthFilter"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app.css" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/config.js" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/config.json" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app.js" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/types.js" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Login/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Common/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/themes/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/app/build/application/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/security/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/securityService.json" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:remember-me key="WM_APP_KEY" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
    </security:http>
```

The problem is that pattern "/pages/Test" does not get restricted for all users (users other than admin). They can access this url.

Whereas when I put 
    
this line in "common" http section then it works.

Note that I want to make it work in above scenario only as I can manage my urls section wise.

Comment: even /pages doesn't work.

Comment: Correct as it should be `/pages/**` but that would effectivly disable your the other http element for all `/pages` URLs. So you need to have `/pages/Test`. (I was just rewriting the comment).

Comment: Tried "/pages/Test", "/pages/Test/**", "/pages/Test**" and "/pages/**" for <security:http name="dbservice"> but nothing worked. I guess common section is overwriting the dbservice section.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case as the pattern should be taken into account and also the ordering is correct (assuming that what you posted here is also what you use).

Comment: Yes, I'm using above code as it is written. That's the reason I can change, compile and test changes suggested by you. ;)